How to build a Hive query to find ids that only have one attribute value?
I have the following table in Hive:
+-----+----------+
|   id|      type|
+-----+----------+
|    1|         A|
|    1|         B|
|    2|         B|
|    3|         A|
|    3|         B|
|    4|         B|
+-----+----------+ 

I am trying to build a query that only counts the id for which there is only the B type.
So the result of this query would be:
+-----+----------+
|   id|      type|
+-----+----------+
|    2|         B|
|    4|         B|
+-----+----------+ 

Do you have any suggestions for constructing such a query?
